# Can I save over a Pokemon Black game with a new save file?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-black-white

I already have a Pokemon Black saved game, but I started another one without thinking if I would leave and delete my past save.

Can I still save the one I started recently or what?

Comment: Have you saved in the new file? If so I am sorry but your previous save file is gone

Answer (score 2):

Pokemon has only ever allowed one save file to exist for one game at one time. In Pokemon Black & White (5th Gen), if you start a new game while another game save exists, **you will be unable to save your new game**.

This is to prevent accidental save-overs of your main game, while still allowing a 'guest' (friend/sibling etc) to have a go of your Pokemon game.

If you want to completely start a new game, you must first erase the old save by pushing and holding <kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Select</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> at the Title screen. You will then be prompted to erase the old Save file.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, either you saved and your previous save is gone or you didn't save and your new save is gone.

I fear it is impossible to have multiple saves, as in any Pokémon game.